# Windows Azure for dummy UNIX gurus?

Tags: remote-desktop, azure, cloud-computing, remote-access, tutorial

After setting up a trial Azure account, how do I access my recently created Visual Studio 14 VM from my Windows 8 laptop?

I tried opening "Remote Desktop Connection", entered the IP address shown in the Azure control panel, and then... nothing (long delay, followed by some "can't connect" message).

Where can I find a really basic tutorial which is straight to the point? I'd like to be able to setup a full Azure environment with Dev servers (VS IDE), Databases, and SQA & Production webservers, then write and deploy a simple Hello World type of app from start to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Azure chooses a random RDP port for you when you create the VM. In the Web portal, you can use the "connect" button in the lower button bar to download a .rdp file that includes the port. The docs are there : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines-b/